# Uploading multiple binary items as part of a batch call on iOS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, photo

I'm trying to make post with more than a photo in Fb using batch request but I keep getting timeout errors from Fb server...

This is my code ..

UIImage *imgFile1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTGps.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgFile1, 0.5);

```
NSString *jsP1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\",\"body\":\"message=My cat photo\",\"attached_files\":\"%@\"}",imageData];

NSString *jsonRequestsArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@,%@,%@]",jsP1,jsP1,jsP1];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonRequestsArray forKey:@"batch"];

FBRequestConnection *connect = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] initWithTimeout:60];

// do Fb request
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// add connection
[connect addRequest:request
  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                  id result,
                      NSError *error) {

      NSLog(@"Result:%@,%@",result,error);

  }];

[connect start];
```

Where am I doing wrong??

Error code is very long so i cut the middle part (i think is the binary images)

2013-04-28 20:03:32.435 trueGps[1887:1a603] Result:(null),Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x14454010 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x14492d40 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?sdk=ios&batch=%5B%7B%20%22method%22%3A%20%22POST%22%2C%20%22relative_url%22%3A%20%22me%2Fphotos%22%2C%22body%22%3A%22message%3DMy%20cat%20photo%22%2C%22attached_files ....

NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x2a90f620 "The request timed out."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200}

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem .. but still have more post with only a photo in every one..

NSString *rel_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",nomeAlbum];

NSString *jsP1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"%@\", \"body\": \"message=My_cat_photo\", \"attached_files\": \"file1\" }",rel_url];

NSString *jsonRequestsArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",jsP1];

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonRequestsArray forKey:@"batch"];

[params setObject:imgFile1 forKey:@"file1"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:rel_url
                             parameters:postParams
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                id result,
                                                NSError *error) {
                            }];
```